# How to create a Qt window behave like a message box?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create a Qt popup window which will behave like a message box in Qt. That means the rest of the GUI must blocked until that popup window is dismissed. This may be a child question, but can anyone pls help me with this ?

Thanks...    :)

Edit:

I want to use forms, labels, buttons and some other widget types in that popup window.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Modal Dialogs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qdialog.html#modal-dialogs)

> A modal dialog is a dialog that blocks
>   input to other visible windows in the
>   same application. Users must finish
>   interacting with the dialog and close
>   it before they can access any other
>   window in the application. Dialogs
>   that are used to request a file name
>   from the user or that are used to set
>   application preferences are usually
>   modal.
>
> The most common way to display a modal
>   dialog is to call its exec() function.
>   When the user closes the dialog,
>   exec() will provide a useful return
>   value. Typically, to get the dialog to
>   close and return the appropriate
>   value, we connect a default button,
>   e.g. "OK", to the accept() slot and a
>   "Cancel" button to the reject() slot.
>   Alternatively you can call the done()
>   slot with Accepted or Rejected.
>
> An alternative is to call
>   setModal(true) or setWindowModality(),
>   then show(). Unlike exec(), show()
>   returns control to the caller
>   immediately. Calling setModal(true) is
>   especially useful for progress
>   dialogs, where the user must have the
>   ability to interact with the dialog,
>   e.g. to cancel a long running
>   operation. If you use show() and
>   setModal(true) together to perform a
>   long operation, you must call
>   QApplication::processEvents()
>   periodically during processing to
>   enable the user to interact with the
>   dialog. (See QProgressDialog.)